# Cannot install Nginx on AWS EC2 AMI2 - Topic :topic: is not found

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx, amazon-ec2

I would like to install Nginx as a reverse proxy on my AWS EC2 (OS: AMI2) instance.

When I try to install `nginx`, I get told that `nginx is available in Amazon Linux Extra topics...`

```
sudo yum install nginx
```

But when I try to install `:topic:`, I am told that `Topic :topic: is not found.`

```
sudo amazon-linux-extras install :topic:
```

I really don't know how to deal with this error.

[image: Terminal Output]

Comment: I've never used AWS but I suspect you need to replace `:topic:` with the package name, either `nginx1.12` or `nginx1` ...

Comment: yes you are absolutely right. I just tried to replace it with Nginx not with nginx1.12 or nginx1. So now it works and the problem is already solved ..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to do the following:

- Type `amazon-linux-extras` to list the packages that are there, and copy the version of nginx, for example nginx1.2
- Then type `sudo amazon-linux-extras install nginx1.2`

Comment: yes absolutely right. That worked for me :)